# How to Insert data in to Junction Object?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have Below VF page with multiple lookup Fields and i want to Insert data from VF page to a Junction Object. when i am trying to save data it is showing me error.kindly correct me where i am doing wrong?[image]

Below is the extension Controller for the page:

```
public class IntralinksExtension {

    public IntralinksExtension(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {

    }
    Public Contact Cont{get;set;}
    public String ContactRecordId {get;set;}
    public string IntragroupId1 {get;set;}

    Public void Save() {

        ContactRecordId = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('id');
        IntragroupId1 = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('ILPG1');

        List<Intralinks_Group_and_Contact_Links__c> IntCnt = [select Id, 
            Contact__c, Intralinks_Portal_Group__c 
            from Intralinks_Group_and_Contact_Links__c];

        if(IntCnt.isEmpty()) {
            IntCnt[0].Contact__c = ContactRecordId;
            IntCnt[0].Intralinks_Portal_Group__c = IntragroupId1;
        }

        Insert IntCnt;
    }

    Public Pagereference Close() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Page:

```
<apex:page Standardcontroller="Contact" extensions="IntralinksExtension" recordSetVar="Intralinks Groups">
<apex:form >

<apex:pageBlock >
    <apex:pageBlockButtons >
        <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!Save}" />
        <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" onclick="window.close()"/>
        <apex:actionStatus startText="(Saving...)" stopText=""  onStop="window.close();" id="closer"/>
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>

    <apex:pageBlockSection Title="New Intralinks Portal Group" Columns="1" >
        <apex:inputField id="Cont1" label="Contact" value="{!Cont.ContactLookup__c}" />

        <apex:inputField id="ILPG1" label="IntraLinks Portal Group" value="{!Cont.Intralinks_Portal_Group__c}"/>
        <apex:inputField id="ILPG2" label="IntraLinks Portal Group" value="{!Cont.Intralinks_Portal_Group__c}"/>
        <apex:inputField id="ILPG3" label="IntraLinks Portal Group" value="{!Cont.Intralinks_Portal_Group__c}"/>
        <apex:inputField id="ILPG4" label="IntraLinks Portal Group" value="{!Cont.Intralinks_Portal_Group__c}"/>
        <apex:inputField id="ILPG5" label="IntraLinks Portal Group" value="{!Cont.Intralinks_Portal_Group__c}"/>
        <apex:inputField id="ILPG6" label="IntraLinks Portal Group" value="{!Cont.Intralinks_Portal_Group__c}"/>
        <apex:inputField id="ILPG7" label="IntraLinks Portal Group" value="{!Cont.Intralinks_Portal_Group__c}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: What's the error you are getting?  Anyway you are checking `IntCnt` list for empty and if yes trying to get first elements. This should be the other way around. If not empty you can get elements

Comment: I am getting below error System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 0
Error is in expression '{!Save}' in component <apex:commandButton> in page addintralinksgrouppage: Class.IntralinksExtension.Save: line 20, column 1

Class.IntralinksExtension.Save: line 20, column 1

Comment: Both fields which i am trying to update are Master Detail Relation ship fields

Comment: can you please add your vf page?

Comment: I have added my VF page

Answer (score 0):

You doing:

```
if(IntCnt.isEmpty()){
    IntCnt[0].Contact__c = ContactRecordId;
```

But list **is empty**, that's why `IntCnt[0].Contact__c` throws System.ListException

Later You're inserting existing record in:

```
Insert IntCnt;
```

You will have

> INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE

SF doesn't allow insert record with existing ID. You should create new junction object.
Try to get your master-detail from cont, not from url parameters

Replace:

```
ContactRecordId = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('id');
IntragroupId1 = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('ILPG1');

List<Intralinks_Group_and_Contact_Links__c> IntCnt = [select Id, Contact__c, 
    Intralinks_Portal_Group__cfrom Intralinks_Group_and_Contact_Links__c];

if(IntCnt.isEmpty()){
    IntCnt[0].Contact__c = ContactRecordId;
    IntCnt[0].Intralinks_Portal_Group__c = IntragroupId1;
}

Insert IntCnt;
```

With:

```
Intralinks_Group_and_Contact_Links__c IntCnt = new Intralinks_Group_and_Contact_Links__c
    (Contact__c = Cont.ContactLookup__c, Intralinks_Portal_Group__c = Cont.Intralinks_Portal_Group__c);
insert IntCnt;
```

Page, make fields as required:

```
<apex:inputField id="Cont1" label="Contact" value="{!Cont.ContactLookup__c}" required="true"/>

<apex:inputField id="ILPG1" label="IntraLinks Portal Group" 
    value="{!Cont.Intralinks_Portal_Group__c}" required="true"/>
```

This will guarantee that values are populated.
And after `<apex:form >` add

```
<apex:pageMessages />
```

That will display your validation error

Comment: I am getting below error System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [Contact, Intralinks Portal Group]: [Contact, Intralinks Portal Group]
Error is in expression '{!Save}' in component <apex:commandButton> in page addintralinksgrouppage: Class.IntralinksExtension.Save: line 22, column 1

Class.IntralinksExtension.Save: line 22, column 1

Comment: you're not populating your page url, check updated answer

Comment: still i am getting the same error message

Comment: add   <apex:pageMessages /> after   <apex:form >

Comment: I would suggest you to read [visual force in practice](https://www.developerforce.com/guides/Visualforce_in_Practice.pdf) that will help you to understand the basics.